# Scrapy Xpath returns empty output

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I try to scrapy this data (the **71**) from this line of code here:

`<span class="text-pill text-pill--steel tooltip tooltipstered" data-options="{&quot;theme&quot;: &quot;white&quot;}">71</span>`

from the website

https://www.attheraces.com//racecard/Hamilton/28-September-2020/1330

I tried

```
class ErgebnisseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'namen'
    allowed_domains = ['www.attheraces.com/']
    start_urls = ['https://www.attheraces.com//racecard/Hamilton/28-September-2020/1330']

def parse(self, response):

starterkomplett = response.xpath('//div[@class="column width--tablet-wide-18"]')

        for rennen2 in starterkomplett:
rating = rennen2.xpath('//span[@class="text-pill text-pill--steel tooltip tooltipstered"]').getall()

yield {
 
              'rennen2_rating' : rating,

        }
```

But I am not getting the "74" rating. Neither with /text() nor without, but with the inspection tool from chrome I can select the span with the aformentioned code... what am I missing here?

With other values on the side the code works, but not for the rating...

I am kind of new and learning, but I did not come any further googleing myself, so I guessed I ask here - again - Sorry for beein such a noob :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the page source

```py
response.xpath("//*[@class='text-pill text-pill--steel tooltip']//text()").getall()
```